# Не работает аудио драйвер [Dummy Output] Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: ubuntu

На ноутбуке `Dell XPS15` были проблемы с аудио драйвером, периодически при запуске системы не работал звук. Решил переустановить `pulseaudio`, теперь звук вообще пропал :)

Попытки решения проблемы:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge alsa-base 
sudo apt-get remove --purge pulseaudio 
sudo apt-get install alsa-base 
sudo apt-get install pulseaudio
```

**Не помогает**

В `/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf` прописать

`options snd-hda-intel model=auto`

**Не помогает**

В настройках аудио в `Output` пишет `Dummy Output`

На `input` нет устройств (ранее был микрофон)

Ставил `PPA` с `audio-dev`, не помогло

В настройках **alsamixer v.1.1.0**
Выставляю все на максимум, не помогает.

alsamixer выводит тип карты:
**HDA Intel PCH**
Чип: **Realtek ALC3266**

Нагуглил инструкцию по установке Realtek дров для Dell XPS15, ссылки на сайте Realtek битые.

Если вы сталкивались с подобной проблемой, подскажите как продебажить и какие еще есть варианты, глухонемой ноутбук это печально :)

---

**Дополнительная информация**

> sudo aplay -l

```
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: ALC3266 Analog [ALC3266 Analog]
  Subdevices: 0/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

Перезапускаю `alsa`

`sudo alsa force-reload`

Есть **Warning**

```
/sbin/alsa: Warning: Processes using sound devices: 1129(pulseaudio). 
Unloading ALSA sound driver modules: snd-seq-midi snd-seq-midi-event snd-seq snd-rawmidi snd-seq-device snd-soc-rt286 snd-soc-rl6347a snd-soc-core snd-compress snd-pcm-dmaengine snd-hda-codec-hdmi snd-hda-codec-realtek snd-hda-codec-generic snd-hda-intel snd-hda-codec snd-hda-core snd-hwdep snd-pcm snd-timer (failed: modules still loaded: snd-hda-codec-hdmi snd-hda-codec-realtek snd-hda-codec-generic snd-hda-intel snd-hda-codec snd-hda-core snd-hwdep snd-pcm snd-timer).
Loading ALSA sound driver modules: snd-seq-midi snd-seq-midi-event snd-seq snd-rawmidi snd-seq-device snd-soc-rt286 snd-soc-rl6347a snd-soc-core snd-compress snd-pcm-dmaengine snd-hda-codec-hdmi snd-hda-codec-realtek snd-hda-codec-generic snd-hda-intel snd-hda-codec snd-hda-core snd-hwdep snd-pcm snd-timer.
```

Далее выполняю:

`pulseaudio -k`

`sudo alsa force-reload`

все ок, нет предупреждений.

`sudo pkill pulseaudio && pulseaudio -D`

**Демон запущен**

Звук появился, но приходится выполнять перезапуск pulseaudio каждый раз при старте системы.

Comment: Просто ради эксперемента - а на других дистрах работает? Федора, Опенсьюзи.

Comment: К сожалению нет возможности проводить тесты, система рабочая, жалко сносить :)

Comment: Закатай весь винт через `Clonezilla Live CD` куда-нибудь и попробуй другой дистрибутив. Качнуть можно тут: http://free.nchc.org.tw/clonezilla-live/stable/ , на флэшку iso пишется через http://tuxboot.sf.net